# PHP Function didn't work for returning value

Tags: php, mysql

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    statusColor($row['status']);
    function statusColor($x) {
        if (stripos($x, '2nd') == true) {
            echo "Best";
        }
    }
```

Note : The data for fetch will return '2nd Shift' or '3rd Shift'.

The above code return nothing. Just blank. Appreciated if you could help me for the solutions.

I am running on PHP 5.3.28.

Answer (score 0):

To know if a `string` contains a `substring` you use the native PHP function `strstr()` or if you want it case sensitive `stristr`. You could do what you want like this:

```
if (strstr($x, '2nd') === true) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `statusColor()` function isn't returning anything because `$row['status']` doesn't contain `2nd`. You need to add an else condition.

Also note the return values of [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

```
function statusColor($x) {
    if (stripos($x, '2nd') !== false) {
        // String contains '2nd'
    } else {
        // String doesn't contain '2nd'
    }
}
```

But as Verhaeren said, you should use [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) if you're only checking whether the string exists or not.